# how to get the service URL or address with the service reference name WCF and C#

Tags: c#, wcf, service-reference

How can i get the address of the service reference. For instance i have a service reference named profile and its address is :

```
http://hostname/services/profile.svc
```

How can i get get this address in c# by specifying the service name, in this case "profile"?
so far i have tried

```
new profile.profileServiceClient()
```

and tried to find anything useful from the watch list but didn't get anything useful.

This might not be a good question but its very useful for me. Will really appreciate your help.

Comment: `new profile.profileServiceClient().Endpoint.Address.Uri`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can u try this, create an object of serviceclient and then use the EndPoint.Address.Uri property

[image]